# method1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

I am new to python and unable to understand 1 error which I am receiving i.e. method1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.
below is my python code for reference.

```
outsidevariable = "This is outside variable"
class class1:
classvariable = "This is class variable"
print("Printing class variable",classvariable)
print("Printing outside variable",outsidevariable)

def method1(self):
    method1variable1 = "method1 variable1"
    print("Printing class variable from method1 ",classvariable)
    print("Printing outside variable from method1 ",outsidevariable)
    print("Printing method1variable1 ",method1variable1)

def method2(self):
    method2variable1= "method2 variable1"
    print("Printing class variable from method1 ",classvariable)
    print("Printing outside variable from method1 ",outsidevariable)
    print("Printing method1variable1 ",self.method1variable1)
    print("Printing method1variable1 ",method2variable1)


c = class1
c.method1()
c.method2()
```

Comment: Your indentation is broken, so your methods ```method1``` and ```method2``` are not understood to belong to your class ```class1```. Indent them correctly.

Comment: `c = class1` *does not create an instance*, it only gives the class another name. You want `c = class1()`.

Comment: There are plenty of issues in your code apart from above comments. The way you're accessing `classvariable`, `self.method1variable1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `c = class1` does not create an instance, it only gives another alias to your class (python's variables actually act like pointers. They aren't the actual object but they are pointer to that object.).

Try:

```
ins = class1()
ins.method1()
ins.method2()
```

Also, I think (a wild guess as you haven't specified anything) you need to change every reference to these variables `method2variable1`, `method1variable1` and `classvariable` to `self.method2variable1`, `self.method1variable1` and `class1.classvariable`.

This

For example,

```
def method2(self):
    self.method2variable1 = "method2 variable1"
    print("Printing class variable from method1", class1.classvariable)
    print("Printing outside variable from method1",outsidevariable)
    print("Printing method1variable1", self.method1variable1)
    print("Printing method1variable1", self.method2variable1)
```

**EDIT:**

To avoid the ambiguity, I have posted my whole code:

```
outsidevariable = "This is outside variable"
class class1:
    classvariable = "This is class variable"
    print("Printing class variable",classvariable)
    print("Printing outside variable",outsidevariable)

    def method1(self):
        self.method1variable1 = "method1 variable1"
        print("Printing class variable from method1 ", class1.classvariable)
        print("Printing outside variable from method1 ", outsidevariable)
        print("Printing method1variable1 ", self.method1variable1)

    def method2(self):
        self.method2variable1= "method2 variable1"
        print("Printing class variable from method1 ", class1.classvariable)
        print("Printing outside variable from method1 ", outsidevariable)
        print("Printing method1variable1 ", self.method1variable1)
        print("Printing method1variable1 ", self.method2variable1)


c = class1()
c.method1()
```

Outputs:

```
Printing class variable This is class variable
Printing outside variable This is outside variable
Printing class variable from method1  This is class variable
Printing outside variable from method1  This is outside variable
Printing method1variable1  method1 variable1
```

Comment: @SeaverOlson I downvoted this. Look at my answer. `print("Printing method1variable1 ",self.method1variable1)` your code has this. Will this work?

Comment: @AbhishekRai the question was about a certain error not the overall code. You help them where they are stuck so they can move onto the next error and figure it out for themselves

Comment: @SeaverOlson You need to know more about SO. The answer is never about the OP. The answer is meant for everybody. Visit Meta to know more.

Comment: @AbhishekRai Please check my answer again. I have mentioned to change every reference of the variable to `self.` or 'class.`. Because as per the name of the variables, it seems like OP wants to have instance variable. And my answer was accepted by OP also. Seems like it has solved his problem.

Comment: Even I have clarified in my answer that I am making the assumption and OP hasn't came back on this. Looks like it really solved his problem. In your answer, you have also made some assumption and corrected the code using those assumptions.

Comment: @abhiarora You probably missed his comment. `Thank you my error is resolve but now there I am getting an error in method1 variable accessing into method2.` ..Read it below

Comment: 1. He hasn't posted that here. 2. If he changes the every reference to self. or class1. as mentioned in my answer. It should resolve it. My answer is working as I have tested it.

Comment: The comment you are talking about is in another answer. Please check.

Comment: `print("Printing method1variable1", self.method1variable1)` This is an unresolved attribute reference  error...because of course it is. :). Can you call another method's variable with `self` in another fucntion? I don't think so sir.

Comment: Dude why it will be if he changes `method1variable1` to `self.method1variable1`. Have you read my answer?

Comment: I have posted `method1` because I don't want to post the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the other answer missed this, however you cannot call method1 variable from method2 like that. You have to make it global. Also, use self in method.

```
outsidevariable = "This is outside variable"
class class1:
    classvariable = "This is class variable"
    print("Printing class variable",classvariable)
    print("Printing outside variable",outsidevariable)

    def method1(self):
        global method1variable1  #Global, so can be accessed by other function
        method1variable1 = 'Method1 variable 1'
        print("Printing class variable from method1 ",class1.classvariable)
        print("Printing outside variable from method1 ",outsidevariable)
        print("Printing method1variable1 ",method1variable1)


    def method2(self, method2variable1):
        self.method2variable1 = method2variable1

        print("Printing class variable from method1 ",class1.classvariable)
        print("Printing outside variable from method1 ",outsidevariable)
        print("Printing method1variable1 ", method1variable1) #Here you are calling variable from method1
        print("Printing method1variable1 ",method2variable1)


c = class1()
c.method1()
c.method2('method2 variable1')
```

Output: -

```
Printing class variable This is class variable
Printing outside variable This is outside variable
Printing class variable from method1  This is class variable
Printing outside variable from method1  This is outside variable
Printing method1variable1  Method1 variable 1
Printing class variable from method1  This is class variable
Printing outside variable from method1  This is outside variable
Printing method1variable1  Method1 variable 1
Printing method1variable1  method2 variable1
```

Comment: The OP has said he wants `method1variable1` to be global? It doesn't even matches with the variable name!. Neither he has mentioned that he wants `method2variable1` to be instance variable.

Answer (score -1):

> method1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

this is occurring because you are not creating a new object with `c = class1`

also you functions think self is an argument because of your indentation

```
outsidevariable = "This is outside variable"
class class1:
    classvariable = "This is class variable"
    print("Printing class variable",classvariable)
    print("Printing outside variable",outsidevariable)

    def method1(self):
        method1variable1 = "method1 variable1"
        print("Printing class variable from method1 ",classvariable)
        print("Printing outside variable from method1 ",outsidevariable)
        print("Printing method1variable1 ",method1variable1)

    def method2(self):
        method2variable1= "method2 variable1"
        print("Printing class variable from method1 ",classvariable)
        print("Printing outside variable from method1 ",outsidevariable)
        print("Printing method1variable1 ",self.method1variable1)
        print("Printing method1variable1 ",method2variable1)


c = class1()
c.method1()
c.method2()
```

I fixed the object creation error and fixed your indentation so the functions are registering self as an object instead of an argument

Comment: Thank you my error is resolve but now there I am getting an error in method1 variable accessing into method2.

Comment: @RaviMishra Check my answer.